# WPF sum values from textbox

Tags: wpf

i have 5 TextBoxes for number. and I want to show sum numbers from textboxes after write. currently showing numbers from textbox, not sum. This is my code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 10 24 0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Hc" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Width="50"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Style="{StaticResource SmallSuccessButton}" Margin="0 10 0 0" Content="Save"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 10 5 0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Sum" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="red">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" Height="26" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" 
                                   Width="60" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

In ViewModel:
 private ObservableCollection _list;

```
    public ObservableCollection<Data> List
    {
        get { return _list;}
        set { _list = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List)); }
    }



    public class MeasureInput
    {
        public float Value { get; set; }

        public MeasureInput(float f)
        {

        }
    }
```

Result must be:

SUM  Textboxes
10    i write 10 and sum set 10
15     i write 5 and sum set 15

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any code that performs the sum, or value to store it. What's your question?

Comment: This code is easy: List.Sum(), but i dont know where to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your ViewModel:

```
public double Sum
{
    get { return List.Sum();}
}
```

And in your XAML, bind to Sum instead of List:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sum}" />
```

Comment: It might also be worth noting you might have to add PropertyChangeListeners to the Data and raise a NotifyPropertyChanged for Sum - otherwise it would not update when the text boxes change.

Answer (score 1):

add to stackpanel

```
<StackPanel  TextBox.TextChanged="OnTextChanged">
....


</StackPanel>
```

then in code behind

```
public void OnTextChanged(routedEvent e,sender variable)
{
int Sum = 0;
    if(e.source is TextBox)
    {
      forearch(Child child in stackpanel.Children)
        {
              if(child is TextBox)
              {
                  TextBox txt = child as TextBox;
                  if(txt.Text  != "") //validation empty textbox
                    Sum+= int.Parse(txt.Text);
               }
        }
    }

}
```